# Pushing view onto navigation controller in tab bar controller does not animate

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a very peculiar problem.

My setup is a `UITabBarController` with two `UINavigationController -> UICollectionViewController` children.

- If I say `navigationController.pushViewController(someVC, animated: true)` in `viewDidAppear`, the view controller is pushed as expected.
- However, if I say `navigationController.pushViewController(someVC, animated: true)` when a cell from the `collectionView` is tapped, the view controller appears, but there is no animation/interactivity when going back (I cannot slide, and the buy button makes the controller instantly disappear).

This is really frustrating because I can think of no explanation. Why would the animations and interactivity work when pushed from `viewDidAppear` but not when pushed from a different function?

Why on earth is this happening, and how can I fix or get around it?

Comment: can you share the code to push viewController from cell delegate?

Comment: @Kamran, after a lot of experimenting, I have noticed that the interactivity is messed up only on the tab that is visible when the app opens. It works perfectly fine in the tab that is not originally visible.

Comment: You are probably doing something differently from the `didSelect` method of your `collectionViewDelegate`. Please share some of your code, if you want to get more help.

Comment: @dvp.petrov, the thing is, if I simply move the bar setup to viewDidAppear and change nothing in didSelect it works, so it can’t have anything to do with what’s in didSelect. Do you still think the code would help? I’ll have to look through old git versions to check if you think that would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have not figured out what is causing this issue, but I did find a (rather inconvenient) solution: Set the tab bar items in `viewDidAppear`. Use a short splash screen or something until then.

I'm not sure what the original problem was, though, so it would be great if anyone else had any explanations!